# Requesting "Always" perrmission for location - IOS EXPO

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, geolocation, background-process

I need to get perrmision "Always" for tracking my location in Background. For Android, it works correctly and good, but on IOS, it requires perrmision "Always" to working, but for IOS, I can't get that perrmision.
I'm using expo-location, and here is part of my code...

```
try {
  let { status: foregroundStatus } =
    await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
  if (foregroundStatus !== "granted") {
    setErrorMsg("Permission to access location was denied");
    return;
  } else {
    const { status: backgroundStatus } =
      await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();

    if (backgroundStatus !== "granted") {
      setErrorMsg("Permission to access location in the background was denied");
      return;
    }
  }

  await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
    accuracy: Location?.Accuracy?.Balanced,
    timeInterval: 5 * 1000,
    showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
    // distanceInterval: 200,
  });
} catch (error: any) {
  setErrorMsg(`Error: ${error.message}`);
}
```

How to fix this ?

Now it gives me this error

`Error fetching location: [Error: One of the NSLocation*UsageDescription keys must be present in Info.plist to be able to use geolocation.];`

I just need 'Always' permission

I tried to get permission for background geolocation, but i can't. It just gives me error

Answer (score 0):

Follow the error, you should edit `Info.plist` and add `NSLocation*UsageDescription` to be able to use Location permision.

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
...
  <!--  Add one of there  -->

  <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>YOUR TEXT</string>

  <key>NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescriptionDictionary</key>
  <dict>
    <key>YOUR-PURPOSE-KEY</key>
    <string>YOUR TEXT</string>
  </dict>

  <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
  <string>YOUR TEXT</string>
...
</dict>
</plist>
```